# Create a program that will input a heart symbol and will stop at the exclamation mark symbol (Call from another class with an argument)

Tags: java

I showed this to my teacher and he said that I was 99% correct. The only problem is that I did not put an argument in the first class. I'm so confused because I don't think I've learned that part yet : (

Class 1:

```
import java.util.*;
public class hearts {

public static void hearts1(String[] args) {


    char heart = '♥';

    for (int i = 0; 1 < 254; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(heart++ + " ");
    }
   }

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Caller {

public static void main(String[] args){

    hearts.hearts1(args);
}
}
```

Comment: I think your teacher meant that you should *read* that hear Symbol from System.in (with a Scanner or the like) or maybe even accept is as parameter to your program (in which case it would be in args[0])

Comment: @Jan what is the topic called for that so I could start learning it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would advise you to not use "magical appeared" numbers in this sort of situation.
Furthermore you have created an endless loop because your loop condition is (1<254) which is alway true because 1 will always be smaller than 254.

Therefore I would write

```
for (char currentChar = heart; currentChar < '❣'; currentChar++) 
{
    System.out.print(currentChar + " ");
}
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < 254; i++)
{
    System.out.print(heart++ + " ");
}
```

And generally said you are not using any arguments in your code...You are passing some arguments but you're never actually using them.
Maybe you should change your first class like this:

```
public static void hearts1(char startChar) {
    char heart = startChar;
    //...
}
```

And then change the calling to this:

```
hearts.hearts1('♥');
```

If you use this approach I would advise you to check if the given char-parameter (in Class1) is within a certain range of characters so you don't end up processing some chars you newver wanted to...

To take the idea with the scanner into consideration you could simply

```
public static hearts1() {  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.outprinln("Enter starting char:");

    String userInput = scanner.next();

    char heart = userInput.charAt(0);

    for (char currentChar = heart; currentChar < '❣'; currentChar++) {
        System.out.print(currentChar + " ");
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

But I don't advise this method because dependingon the user input it takes quite long for the program to print out the chars and furthermore it's really hard for the user to give the heart symbol as an input.

I hope this answers your question (partly)

Greetings Raven

Comment: Thank you, Raven. I edited my codes and I showed it to my teacher. He gave me a big thumbs up!